# mgf of $f(x)=\frac{1}{2 \beta} e^{-|x-\alpha|/ \beta}$

Tags: statistics

$f(x)=\frac{1}{2 \beta} e^{-|x-\alpha|/ \beta}$ , $-\infty < x < \infty$, $-\infty < \alpha < \infty$, $\beta >0$.

Now I need the mgf of f(x). This is the exercise of 2.30 (c) from Statistical Inference - George Casella, Roger L. Berger. I doubt the official solution is wrong.

My attempt is to divide the whole integral into two parts. But I cannot get the exact answer.

Comment: it sounds like you have the correct approach, can you be more specific about what is going wrong for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\frac{1}{2\beta }\exp (-\left \vert x-\alpha \right \vert /\beta
)=\left \{ 
\begin{array}{cc}
\dfrac{1}{2\beta }\exp ((\alpha -x)/\beta ) & \text{if }x\geq \alpha  \\ 
\dfrac{1}{2\beta }\exp ((x-\alpha )/\beta ) & \text{if }x<\alpha 
\end{array}%
\right. \text{.}
\end{equation*}
By definition of MGF, we have
\begin{equation*}
M_{X}(t)=E[e^{tx}]=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }e^{tx}f(x)dx\text{,}
\end{equation*}
or, equivalently,
\begin{equation*}
M_{X}(t)=\int_{\alpha }^{\infty }e^{tx}\dfrac{1}{2\beta }\exp ((\alpha
-x)/\beta )dx+\int_{-\infty }^{\alpha }e^{tx}\dfrac{1}{2\beta }\exp
((x-\alpha )/\beta )dx\text{.}
\end{equation*}
Given $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{R}_{++}$, direct
calculations yield
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\alpha }^{\infty }e^{tx}\dfrac{1}{2\beta }\exp ((\alpha -x)/\beta )dx=-%
\frac{\exp \left( \alpha t\right) }{2(t\beta -1)}\text{ for }t<\frac{1}{%
\beta }
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\infty }^{\alpha }e^{tx}\dfrac{1}{2\beta }\exp ((x-\alpha )/\beta )dx=%
\frac{\exp \left( \alpha t\right) }{2(t\beta +1)}\text{ for }t>-\frac{1}{%
\beta }\text{.}
\end{equation*}
Hence, it follows
\begin{equation*}
M_{X}(t)=-\frac{\exp \left( \alpha t\right) }{2(t\beta -1)}+\frac{\exp
\left( \alpha t\right) }{2(t\beta +1)}=\frac{e^{t\alpha }}{1-t^{2}\beta ^{2}}
\text{, with }-1/\beta <t<1/\beta \text{.}
\end{equation*}
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome.